# Python requests, get() without a protocol?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Say I have a lot of links, some of them are HTTP, some of them are HTTPS, some have www., some don't.
is there a way in requests to send a request to the domain itself? for example

```
response = requests.get('facebook.com', headers=headers)
```

or I will have to do Try catch for different requests and try HTTP, and HTTPS, etc?

edit:
right now im using this:

```
        try:
            response = requests.get('https://' +url, headers=headers)
        except:
            response= requests.get('http://'+url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Are you using Django? or simple python script.

Comment: `requests` forces you to provide a schema, that is `http://`, `https://`, `ftp://` etc. However, most sites (those that follow the standard at least) will auto-redirect requests for `http` to `https` (`'http://google.com'` or `'http://facebook.com'` will work just fine)

Comment: just a simple script

Comment: This is not Question related to Python inbuilt but more like Logic of code to look into.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `requests` module I would suggest to simply make sure the link is valid, e.g.

```py
url = url if url.startswith('http') else ('http://' + url)
response = requests.get(url, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: They dont, all of the list is just domains, all of them are 'facebook.com' or 'bing.com' etc.

Comment: @Boris I suppose you are suggesting using `urllib.parse.urlparse` right? But since the attribute `ParseResultBytes.scheme` is not settable, one still needs to somehow apply the above logic